# Rewrite Page Parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, rewrite-rules

i have a page call "city"

```
http://localhost/wordpress/city/
```

and it get details from mysql by url id like

```
http://localhost/wordpress/city/?id=paris
```

and i want to change it like

```
http://localhost/wordpress/city/paris
```

and the real link of city page in wordpress is

```
http://localhost/wordpress/index.php?p=5
```

I am trying do add RewriteRule in htaccess and it doesn't work
also i try `add_rewrite_rule` and it doesn't work

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_mypage_rule' );

function add_mypage_rule(){
add_rewrite_tag("%id%", '(\d+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^city/([^/]*)/?','index.php?p=5&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here but from what you've posted it seems like this would be an ideal situation for a custom post type and taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

If `city` belongs to the `page` post type, then your rule should either be:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^city/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?pagename=city&id=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

or:

```
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^city/([^/]*)/?',
    'index.php?page_id=5&id=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
```

Using `p`, the query will assume post type is `post`, not `page`.

Also, if your code uses `$_GET['id']` to fetch the value, this will no longer work with a rewrite rule. You will need to use `get_query_var('id')` instead. If you don't have access to the code, you can set it in an action that fires before the code tries to get that value:

```
function wpd_set_id() {
    if( false !== get_query_var( 'id', false ) ){
        $_GET['id'] = get_query_var( 'id' );
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_query', 'wpd_set_id' );
```

I also suggest using a more unique query var than `id`!